# I am not able to delete the seller_id attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not able to edit any product from my backend and it's showing:

```
""Source model "marketplace/source_option" not found for attribute "seller_id"
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/local/Ced/CsMarketplace/Model/Layout.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/lagootug/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/lagootug/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Please help me with steps.

Comment: Do you have the Medma_MarketPlace extension installed?

Answer (score 3):

Find in the table `eav_attribute` row with `attribute_code = seller_id` and remove it or alternatively remove value of `source_model` column